# Asking people if they'd like to try a question.

Tags: word-choice

Would it be correct to say, "Any take on this question?", when I ask any maths question in a group of people?

Also, any alternatives to it?

The reason I am unsure of this usage is that according to [Cambridge Dicitionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-on-someone-something), take on something means:

> *to fight or compete against someone or something*

Comment: (Although of course a teacher *could* say to the class *Does anyone want to **take on this question? / take this question on?***)

Comment: Do you *want* to use the "fight against" meaning of the phrase, or do you want to avoid that interpretation?

Comment: The phrase "Take On" means to fight or compete.  For example, "I am going to take on city hall and demand they enforce the no parking rules."  In your question you are not using the  phrase "take on" you are asking what someone's "take" is on something.  Find your definition under the word 'take', meaning something similar to 'opinion'.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two similar but different idioms.  "have a take on (something)" and "to take on (something)"

> Have a take on (something)

Here, "take" is a noun and this expression means to have an opinion or impression about something. E.g. do you have a take on why John's been acting strangely lately?

> To take on (something)

Here, "take on" is a verb and means to attempt or to fight/compete against. E.g. Do any of you want to take on the math problem I've written on the board?

Answer (score 0):

A "take on" something can also mean an interpretation of it, eg "That's my take on it, at least".

See the Noun section [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take):

> (Noun)1.1 A particular version of or approach to something. ‘his own
>   whimsical take on life’

With this usage, you **could** say "Any takes (note plural) on this question?", which is a contracted version of "Are there any takes on this question?".

However, it would be more idiomatic to say *"Does anyone have a take on this?"*, which means *"Would anyone here like to share their interpretation of this?"*

I'm not sure if this is appropriate: it depends on how ambiguous the question is.  If you were to ask a question whose meaning is obvious, it's not really appropriate to ask people for their "interpretation" of it:  you just want them to proceed with the obvious interpretation and solve it.  However, if a question is ambiguous then it can be interpreted, or approached, in different ways, and in this instance you could ask people for their "take" on it.  In that case you would not necessarily be asking them to solve it, you might just be asking them to reformulate the question in a more clear way.

Answer (score 0):

'Take' means much the same as 'opinions' in that sentence.
It is functioning as a noun while the 'on' is a preposition *connected to* the verb 'have' in the implied words "Does anyone have ..."
In contrast, the dictionary entry quoted is the definition of the phrasal verb, 'to take on'.
Can anyone tell me the correct term/expression where I wrote *connected to*?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Max Williams' dictionary reference, [here](https://architecturedesignprimer.wordpress.com/tag/concept/) is how a university professor of architecture defines the phrase in his blog (under an entry for "The Concept"):

> "Having ‘a take on’ something means having a position on it."

Whether one agrees with this definition or not, it shows that the phrase is in use across multiple disciplines.

The important thing when teaching math in a collaborative group setting is to vary the questions you ask your students so the questions don't become repetitive or boring. Students often find "word problems" in math particularly challenging, and teaching them the *patterns* found within the problems by asking the following and similar questions helps them to cut through irrelevant aspects and find how to express and solve them mathematically.

Alternatives to and variations on "Any take on this question?" might include some of the following:

> 1. Does anyone want to talk through how to solve this question?
> 2. How can we express this question in mathematical terms?
> 3. What math issues does this question present?
> 4. Are there aspects of this question that do not relate to a mathematical solution?
> 5. Is this question similar to others we have examined before? If so, how did we solve them?
>
> ... and so forth.